# Reading in long double in the C programming language

Tags: c, variables

How do I read in a long double in C?

Comment: as pointed out, read from where?(the source). Is it a file, console, another variable, memory ... etc ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`long double x; scanf("%Lf", &x);`

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that "long double" is a synonym for "double" on Visual Studio.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericflee/archive/2004/06/10/152852.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Either hrnt's answer (`scanf("%Lf", &x)`) or

```
long double x;
if(read(fd,&x,sizeof(x))!=sizeof(x)) printf("Oops\n");
```

the question is very vague.

Comment: If it's C, and not necessarily on Unix, wouldn't fread be better?

Comment: I think read() is equally portable. I doubt there's any difference unless you use fscanf on the same file.

Comment: Thomas, I was talking about de facto portability, not standards. For what I can tell by the question, OP doesn't care much about either.

Comment: hacker: Are you saying that read and file descriptors, as shown in your example code above, will work on Windows?

Comment: Thomas, last time I checked (over 10 years ago, I'm afraid) it worked on Windows.

Comment: hacker: Ok, in that case I have no complaint. (But hey, it doesn't work on TOPS-20!)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the format specifier %ld for reading long double variables.

Comment: %ld is long decimal, not long double.